# Creating 3d printable model - non manifold issues

Tags: modifiers

[image]

[image]

[blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjAIpCX-5BNSh8ZyfJG57LJ1-W50WQ?e=PkkGrx)

I am using a 3d model https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/tool/ender-3-front-pi-case to create a slightly altered version of the Pi 4 Base stl (ie. the model with the Octoprint logo). I am attempting to reduce the logo size, add 18 vent holes and add a switch hole too. I know there are variants of this pi case but really would like to include the Octoprint logo. I have tried other variants of an Octoprint vented logo but they have been such a pain that this seems to be the simplest way.

To do this, I imported the "Pi 4 base" stl, reduced the size of the logo vertices on the x and z axis (leaving y ensures thickness of wall is intact), created solid vent shapes and a circle (called Yvents and Ycircle in my blender files) and used boolean difference to apply these to the Pi 4 base model (with the smaller logo already applied). The issue I have is this creates numerous manifold edges and, when I export the new model to a slicer (in my case VoxelMaker), supports are added everywhere I would expect except the vents, which I think is due to the non manifold issues. I have had so many issues with amending models using simple blender tools and the result being "damaged" 3d models, I feel like giving up on Blender altogether. I end up having to fix every dodgy edge, faces and vertices individually as Clean Up tools end up creating faces over designed gaps in the model walls. I have attached screen prints of the blender issues, plus how these appear in the slicer plus a link to a packed blender file. The problem model in the file is saved as "Pi 4 base small print". The original is "Pi 4 base".

Answer (score 2):

You have three kinds of problems.  Two are easy enough to solve:

1. There are some doubled vertices.

   - switch to vertex select
   - select all
   - <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the merge menu
   - select by distance.
2. You have some interior faces.

   - Deselect all (short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>
   - Use the *Select* → *Select all by Trait* → *Interior faces* menu entry to select the interior faces
   - <kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the delete menu
   - select *faces* from the menu
3. Some strange geometry around the vent in front.  To see it

   - Deselect all (short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>
   - *Select* → *Select all by Trait* → *Non Manifold*
   - result:
     [image: remaining non-manifold geometry]

I don't know how you want to fix this, but if you zoom in on the vent you'll see that there are vertices that I *think* should be merged but aren't, for example:

[image: Example of "near miss" vertices]

There are a lot of verts and edges involved in this, so I didn't want to attempt it by hand; but I think you'll need to fix it before you can print.

EDIT:  I've added my version of the file as it appears after step 3.  The only remaining non-manifold geometry is selected.

[image]

Comment: I did the select by distance for the circular hole and that is ok. However the 16 vents are a complete mess even though I followed the b

Comment: I did the select by distance for the circular hole and that is ok. However the 16 vents are a complete mess even though I followed the creation of those holes using a boolean difference operator, with very simple shapes in the YVents object. All the videos online suggest using this method. It still created non manifold edges that I have no idea how to deal with. the second option deleted all the faces so the object is even more non-manifold than it was before. I may look for something other than Blender. I will try copying the lower vent vertices over the top to see if usable faces are added

Comment: If you followed the steps exactly, your file would look the one I just added to the question.  Does it?